# How to version Code First and WebAPI?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, versioning

I build an Entity Framework Code First database using entity framework:

[image: My version 1 diagram]

I'll hook this up by versioning off my url as well:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Then I implement a 'super-duper-not-backwards-compatible' function so I need to make changes to my backing context and put some business logic in my WebAPI:[image: My version 2 diagram]

I update the version on the url routing:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/v2/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

**Problem:** Version 1 no longer works. It will fire an error stating "`The model backing the 'xyzContext' context has changed since the database was created.`"

**How do I deal with this scenario in a way that allows for backwards compatibility for clients that aren't able to update to version 2?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make v2  scenario work, you have to use a route template like this:

```
"api/{v2}/{controller}/{id}"
```

[ASP.NET Web API: Using Namespaces to Version Web APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/08/using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis.aspx)

Comment: Thank you that's an interesting read. I take it this method cancels out the 'The model backing the 'xyzContext' context has changed since the database was created.' error?

Comment: Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);  //try adding this to your Globel.asax file

Answer (score 1):

This error has nothing to do with the routing but it is indicating that your model has changed ex, you added a `Address` property to your `Person` class. You can use [migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) to keep the database in sync with your models.